# Color Marks for different rows in TABLEAU

Tags: colors, rows, tableau-api

I am trying to color the price difference based on cluster
And the product IDs based on who pays for Logistics. But somehow I do not know how to apply two colour marks for two different rows. Can anyone help me with it? Screenshot is attached. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNSpL.png)

Comment: It's not that clear what you want to do. You want to colour the Product ID field based on Logisitcs AND separately colour the price difference on Cluster? So you would have 2 different fields with 2 different colours on each row?

Comment: Yes, I need to know who paid for Logistics of each product (either supplier or buyer) and it should be presented in two different colors (i.e. Grey and blue) rather than cluster (red and orange).

Answer (score 0):

As you want to colour a dimension column as well as a measure, the placeholder technique could be your best option. Create a dummy field

```
MIN(0)
```

Put this to Columns 4 times. Use these to create 2 dual axis columns. This enables putting any dimension / measure into the column and also to colour those by a different value.

It's a long topic, please refer to this URL for full guidance: https://tarsolutions.co.uk/blog/using-the-placeholder-for-advanced-tableau-tables/

Comment: Thank you! I will try to do it.